# How do I add a layer to a neural network in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

[image]

I have the above Layer Recurrent Neural Net from Matlab. I wanted to know, just how do I add an extra Hidden layer to this? Am I not understanding this correctly or is there only one layer here - with 3 neurons and 1 feedback loop? Could someone please rectify this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, did you see the Hidden part in the graph above? copy the structure to form another Hidden layer, and let the output port of the first hidden neural unit to stream into the second hidden layer's first input port, with the second input point connected with the output port of itself. Then let the output port of the second hidden layout stream into the W port of Output unit.That's Okay now.

Comment: How do I do it Graphically? I did this simply using the command line stuff.

Comment: Can u just use the MATLAB Neural Network Tool Box? There's many recipe for u to handle this sort of problems, it's very easy, try to check the help document within MATLAB, like 'help bp' see if it pop up a window telling u how to use the tool box of ANN?